# definitions, lemmas, problems in bold

Tags: bold, amsthm

I use the amsthm package, but somehow all definitions, lemmas, problems are in normal text.. I want them in bold as usual. 
How can I control that?

What I ment is that the text
"Lemma 1:"  is not in bold

part of that I use

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{probw}{Problem}
\renewcommand\theprobw{\unskip}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example that we can copy and test without having to guess the rest of your preamble and class.

Comment: That is still not something we can use or test.

Comment: See this for an explanation of the term minimal example: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3929, it is the most highly regarded commodity on this site

Comment: Which font family do you use? Do you maybe use a text font that doesn't feature a **bold** weight? (For instance, the `ebgaramond` font package provides upright and italic font shapes, but only in "normal" weight -- no bold.) Please also tell us which document class you use and which other packages you load.

Comment: Incidentally, defining an unnumbered theorem-like environment the way you do for `probw` (with the redefinition of `\theprobw`) is rather hackish. Why not execute `\newtheorem*{probw}{Problem}`, i.e., use the "starred" version of the `\newtheorem` macro?

Comment: Thanks for the helps, I found it out, it was this row
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pad} % garamond

Comment: and also\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}